# Angular bootstrap pagination force-ellipses

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-bootstrap

This plnkr I created shows the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/YQAUCg5vjcgS1BEGB4nY?p=preview
shortly, I've got many pages and i set this attribute: `force-ellipses = true` to show the dots instead 200 pages. But doesn't work. I use angular bootstrap 2.3.1 and I think this is the problem. But I can't use another version so, is there any way to fix it?

```
<pagination
    num-pages="noOfPages" 
    current-page="currentPage" 
    max-size="maxSize"
    boundary-link-numbers="true"
    rotate="true"
    force-ellipses="true">
</pagination>
```

Comment: _I use angular bootstrap 2.3.1_ your fiddle is using v0.3.0. If you were using v2.3.1 you'd be using the attribute directive `uib-pagination` rather than the element level directive `<pagination>`. So what version are you actually using?

Comment: I'm sorry, this one: <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script> because I use <pagination> and not <uib-pagination>

Comment: In that case, I don't think it's possible as they didn't include the ellipses (or the `force-ellipses` until a later version, however, the reason it's showing 200 pages is that you have `max-size` set to 200, change it to something like 10 which [looks a lot better](http://plnkr.co/edit/CPnFAgiFNf0zFOSxAVhu?p=preview)

Comment: Yes but if i show only 10 the other results are lost.. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh ok, I've just seen now your plunker! I got it

Comment: You are very wrong, it wouldn't be a very good pagination if there were lost :P

Answer (score 0):

Actually, implementation of uib-pagination is not correct. In the recent version, the syntax is

```
<div uib-pagination total-items="total_items" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-link-numbers="true" rotate="false"></div>
```

Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4daZ6VsVmbLjaSAyFARt?p=preview) for implementation

Apart from this. I use dir-pagination i feel that more convenient and easy.

Check this [angularUtils](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils) repo

and Plunker for [dir-pagination](http://embed.plnkr.co/1Zy68t9ifg5SubucKS7V/)

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't change the Angular bootstrap version. I tried but i get errors like "unknown provider $modal" and I don't know way! So there aren't solutions using my version of Angular bootstrap?

Comment: change the version and change `$modal to $uibModal` wherever you use modal. it will work. tell me if you face any other problems. migration is very simple @End.Game

Comment: @End.Game. did you try what I said?

Comment: Nope, I didn't try sorry. The big problem is that the web app I'm working at  now is using Uikit as front-end Framework. But the Uikit pagination isn't good enough. So I decided to use the bootstrap way! Including angular bootstrap and uikit the web application works well with no problems. But I think there are some conflicts with the new version of angular bootstrap (the modal for example). I don't use bootstrap modals in my app. Only Uikit. But i have anyway the error

Comment: I faced the same errors what you are facing now. The update with ui-bootstrap changed few usages of modules. such as `$modal - $uibModal`. The older one has lots of bugs. better upgrade and it your choice to make. @End.Game